# TCD pivotTable ADODB Access

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I a module I declared constant variables

```
Public Const ADODB_PROVIDER = "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
Public Const PATH_DB = "E:\BkUpData\Projets\Access\GarageHellMotors\facturation_be_test.accdb"
```

In an other module this function called on workbook load event

```
Public Function fWkBookCnxAdd()

Dim objWBConnect As WorkbookConnection

Set objWBConnect = ThisWorkbook.Connections.Add( _
Name:="tcd", Description:="", _
ConnectionString:=ADODB_PROVIDER & _
"Data Source=" & PATH_DB, _
CommandText:="SELECT * FROM qryFactureSumMonthYear", _
lCmdtype:=xlCmdSql)

End Function
```

See l[enter link description here](http://www.o2website.hol.es/developpez/ADODBCnx.png)

On a tab, I added a commandButton with this code below on click even

```
Private Sub cmdTcd_Click()

Dim oPivotCache As PivotCache
Dim oPtTable As PivotTable

ActiveSheet.Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Clear 

' Create a PivotTable cache
Set oPivotCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlExternal,  _
SourceData:=ThisWorkbook.Connections(1))

Set oPtTable = oPivotCache.CreatePivotTable( _ 
TableDestination:=Range("A3"), _
TableName:="tcd")
```

But This code below is wrong and I don't know where

> Set oPivotCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlExternal,  _
>       SourceData:=ThisWorkbook.Connections(1))

so the command below generates  a Run-Time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error

> Set oPtTable = oPivotCache.CreatePivotTable( _
>       TableDestination:=Range("A3"), _
>       TableName:="tcd") ' ---> Error  1004 
>       ...Code

Thanks by advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution below

In a module

```
Public Const ADODB_PROVIDER = "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
Public Const PATH_DB = "E:\Access\test.accdb"

Public Function fWkBookCnxDelAll()
Dim oWkBookCnx As WorkbookConnection

For Each oWkBookCnx In ThisWorkbook.Connections
    oWkBookCnx.Delete
Next oWkBookCnx
End Function

Public Function fWkBookCnxInitAll()    
Dim objWBConnect As WorkbookConnection

Set objWBConnect = ThisWorkbook.Connections.Add( _
Name:="tcd", Description:="", _
ConnectionString:=ADODB_PROVIDER & _
"Data Source=" & PATH_DB, _
CommandText:="SELECT * FROM qryFactureSumMonthYear", _
lCmdtype:=xlCmdSql)
End Function
```

On Thisworkbook load event, the code below

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 fWkBookCnxDelAll
 fWkBookCnxInitAll    
End Sub
```

On command button click event  of a worksheet,  the code below

```
Private Sub cmdAddTCD_Click()

Dim oCnx As WorkbookConnection
Dim oPc As PivotCache
Dim oPt As PivotTable

ActiveSheet.Range("G7").CurrentRegion.Clear '

' Create a PivotTable cache
Set oCnx = ThisWorkbook.Connections("tcd")
Set oPc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, _
SourceData:=oCnx)

' Create a tcd.
Set oPt = oPc.CreatePivotTable( _
TableDestination:=ActiveSheet.Range("G4"), _
TableName:="tcd")

With oPt
    .SmallGrid = False

    .AddFields _
    RowFields:="idfacture", _
    RowFields:="libelle", _
    ColumnFields:="PeriodemontYear"

    .AddDataField _
    Field:=oPt.PivotFields("montant") _
 End With
End Sub
```

A new TCD is now created